# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitize' of null after submitting the form Angular 9, but it was working fine in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form in my application after clicking the submit button it will call the insert function. API gets success and also I'm getting response from the backend.

But after calling the insert function, it directly goes to error method it says Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitize' of null eventhough there is no error in API.

Data console is not printing.

```js
insert(model) {
    this.dataService.insertData(model).subscribe(data => {
         console.log('Data', data);
    }, error => {
         console.log('Error', error);
    });
}
```

```js
Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sanitize' of null
    at JhiAlertService.factory (ng-jhipster.js?8ee9:3097)
    at JhiAlertService.addAlert (ng-jhipster.js?8ee9:3037)
    at JhiAlertService.success (ng-jhipster.js?8ee9:2945)
    at TapSubscriber.eval [as _tapNext] (notification.interceptor.ts?ccb8:34)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js?c4cc:45)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js?1453:53)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js?b7f3:1741)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js?09c9:28173)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:420)
```

Comment: Could you update with some more information? Would need to see what dataService.insertData is doing as it looks like that is what is throwing the error.

Comment: insertData(request?: any): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post(url, request); }

Comment: ok and how about your model object being sent. it looks like something there is null/undefined and ng-jhipster.js isn't a fan of that